# QPropertyAnimation not running immediately when QAbstractAnimation::start() is called

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to make a simple multi-page widget with `QStackedWidgets` in Qt Creator with `Qt 4.8.6`. The goal is to have a `QLabel` and `QProgressBar` fade away after the progress bar reaches full value. I thought the best way to achieve this was using `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` and `QPropertyAnimation` in tandem as seen below.

```
void MainWindow::AnimateStartScreen()
{
    //QSound::play("./Audio/THX-DeepNote-48Khz.wav");
    sleep(5);

    logoEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
    logoAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(logoEffect, "opacity");
    ui->startLogo->setGraphicsEffect(logoEffect);
    logoAnimation->setDuration(2000);
    logoAnimation->setStartValue(1);
    logoAnimation->setEndValue(0);
    logoAnimation->start();

    progressBarEffect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
    progressBarAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(progressBarEffect, "opacity");
    ui->startProgressBar->setGraphicsEffect(progressBarEffect);
    progressBarAnimation->setDuration(2000);
    progressBarAnimation->setStartValue(1);
    progressBarAnimation->setEndValue(0);
    progressBarAnimation->start();

    sleep(3);
}
```

Which is then called by the `main` method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.HideTitleBar();
    w.CenterWidget();
    //QMainWindow::showFullScreen();
    w.show();
    w.IncrementProgressbar();
    w.AnimateStartScreen();
    w.ChangePageTo(1);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here lies the problem. I want this animation to finish before I change the page like so:

```
void MainWindow::ChangePageTo(int page)
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(page);
}
```

Is there a way I can delay page change until my animation is complete? When I comment out the page change, the animation doesn't seem to even start until `QApplication::exec()` is called in my `main` method, evident by a 8 second waiting period (the combination of both sleep calls), rather than a 5 second delay before `QAbstractAnimation::start()` is called.

I believe what is happening is that the `sleep(3)` line is stopping the thread in which the GUI is running on, hence delaying the start of the animation for three seconds. When the sleep call has completed, I wonder if the animation tries to continue, but because of the page change,there is just no visible effect from the quick transition.

How can I make a 3 second delay without stopping the thread that the animation is running off of? Or are there any other suggestions that will produce the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe what is happening is that the sleep(3) line is stopping the thread in which the GUI is running on

Almost certainly.  For the animation to run you need to keep the message queue running which, in the code you've posted, won't occur until the subsequent call to `a.exec()`.

If you really need to block execution of `MainWindow::AnimateStartScreen` until the animation has completed then perhaps a better idea would be to replace the call to `sleep(3)` with...

```
while (progressBarAnimation->state() != QAbstractAnimation::Stopped)
  QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

(Although you might have to play about with the flags pass to `QCoreApplication::processEvents` to get the precise behaviour you require.)

Comment: Such infinite loops is a big overhead and unnecessary CPU usage.

Comment: In what way is it an infinite loop?  `QCoreApplication::processEvents` will process those events currently queued and then return.  If a timeout is required then call the overload that allows a timeout to be specified (hence my comment about specifying the flags etc.).

Comment: I mean, that you are not waiting event, but every step do a call of `processEvents`. It's quite heavy operation. There is a `QEventLoop` class for such things. Check my answer.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov -- we appear to find ourselves at odds rather unnecessarily.  The point I think we're both pushing is that the event queue must be active in order for the animation to progress.  Given that the OP invoked `sleep(3)` I assumed `MainWindow::AnimateStartScreen` should to block until the animation was complete.  If that's not a requirement then connecting to the `QAbstractAnimaion::finished` signal -- as you suggest -- is a better option.  With regard to your comment about `QEventLoop` the fact is that `QEventLoop::exec` is just a wrapper for `QCoreApplication::processEvents`.

Comment: @G.M. You are correct on the blocking until the animation is complete.

Comment: After re-reading your answer, I believe we may be at a misunderstanding. I am trying to block execution of `QMainWindow::ChangePageTo(int)` until the animation has finished.

Comment: `QEventLoop::exec` will wait for events via OS calls. So it will not load CPU if there will be no messages. But your loop will load CPU on 100%, even if there will be nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use next pattern for non-blocking waiting (instead of sleep):

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect( progressBarAnimation, &QAbstractAnimaion::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit );
loop.exec();
```